# How to embed a Salesforce File/ContentVersion into a VisualForce rendered PDF?

Tags: visualforce, pdf, base64

I've tried some searching and it's unclear to me if what I want to do is possible in Salesforce. I have an image file attached to a Salesforce Case, and I want to use an `<apex:page showHeader="false" renderAs="pdf">` to build a PDF with that file embedded in it.

The image is a drawn signature, to produce a signed PDF, so this image is confidential.

I've tried an image that looks something like:

```
<apex:image url="{!imageURL}"></apex:image>
```

Where the imageUrl in my Aura controller is something like

```
    public String imageURL{
        get {
            List<ContentVersion> vers = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
            ContentVersion v = vers.get(0);
            return '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=' + v.ContentDocumentId;
        }
    }
```

This renders a broken image in the PDF.

I've also tried to Base64 encode the image and pass that to the template, something like:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{!imageContent}"/>
```

With the controller code:

```
    public String imageContent {
        get {
            List<ContentVersion> vers =   [SELECT Id, VersionData FROM ContentVersion ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC];
            ContentVersion v = vers.get(0);
            return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(v.VersionData);
        }
    }
```

When viewing the visualforce page (I created a tab for it) in both cases the image appears as a broken image using an icon that was created in 1927:

[image: this image is from before when I was born]

If I spit out the image base64 contents directly onto the page:

```
<p>"{!imageContent}"</p>
```

And I copy that content and then in vanilla HTML I build an image with that base64 encoded data as the src, the image renders properly. So I know this is a valid base64 encoding of the jpg binary data.

Is it possible to embed an image from a File / ContentVersion in a VisualForce rendered PDF?

Comment: Try to form a URL like -- 
<apex:image url="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/contentId"/>

Comment: @C.Praveenkumar that still returns the broken image, same with `<apex:image value="...">` (you used `url=`)

Comment: Try using ContentDistribution instead of Content Version Object

Comment: Or you can refer this link if it suits your requirement better
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2014/04/building-content-rich-visualforce-pages-with-salesforce-crm-content

Comment: Here you have the solution:
[https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381102/preview-entire-contentversion-not-just-1st-page/381182#381182](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/381102/preview-entire-contentversion-not-just-1st-page/381182#381182)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to preview a entire ContentVersion file **using a visualforce page**:

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="PreviewContentVersionCTR">
    <apex:iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!versionData}" height="700px"/>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class PreviewContentVersionCTR {

    private final String versionData;

    public PreviewContentVersionCTR() {
        ContentVersion cv = [SELECT Id, VersionData FROM ContentVersion LIMIT 1];       
        versionData = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cv.VersionData);
    }

    public String getVersionData() {
        return versionData;
    }
}
```