# Preview entire ContentVersion (not just 1st page)

Tags: pdf, contentversion, preview

I am using the following command to preview a PDF ContentVersion file inside a LWC:
/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=SVGZ&versionId=0687Z000002EkVc&operationContext=CHATTER

But this just preview the 1st page of the pdf.

Does anyone know **how preview a entire pdf**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to preview a entire ContentVersion file **using a visualforce page**:

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="PreviewContentVersionCTR">
    <apex:iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!versionData}" height="700px"/>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class PreviewContentVersionCTR {

    private final String versionData;

    public PreviewContentVersionCTR() {
        ContentVersion cv = [SELECT Id, VersionData FROM ContentVersion LIMIT 1];       
        versionData = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cv.VersionData);
    }

    public String getVersionData() {
        return versionData;
    }
}
```